# Jinja2 condition not matching within an expression, how to resolve this?

Tags: jinja2

I am currently having troubles with the first `if` statement in a Jinja2 template resolving to `else` even though both conditions are met:

```
{%- elif frontend_type == 'beast' -%}
{{ radosgw_frontend_type }} {{ 'ssl_' if radosgw_frontend_ssl_certificate and haproxy_frontend_ssl_termination is sameas false else '' }}endpoint={{ _rgw_binding_socket }}{{ ' ssl_certificate='+radosgw_frontend_ssl_certificate if radosgw_frontend_ssl_certificate else '' }}
{%- endif -%}
```

The problematic snippet seems to be `and haproxy_frontend_ssl_termination is sameas false` as the other condition works fine. I am not sure why this condition is not met even though it seems to work in another template when encapsulated in `{% %}`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your problem is the use of the `sameas` test.  From [the documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#sameas):

> sameas(value, other)
>
> Check if an object points to the same memory address than another object:

That's almost never what you want to do.  If you're checking to see if an expression is false, you don't need to explicitly compare it to `false`.  E.g., you could simply write:

```
{{ 'ssl_' if radosgw_frontend_ssl_certificate and not haproxy_frontend_ssl_termination else '' }}
```

Comment: Confirmed this was the issue. Thanks!